# how can i fetch random images from Astronomy photo of the day api in Javascript website

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I tried to fetch current images from NASA's Astronomy Photo of the Day (APOD)
But now i am trying to fetch images randomly without using dates
Is it possible?
If yes then how?

here's the code

```
const fetchAPOD = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY")
    const data = await response.json()
    displayData(data)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

const displayData = data => {
  document.querySelector('.title').textContent = data.title
  document.querySelector('.date').textContent = data.date
  document.querySelector('.picture').src = data.url
  document.querySelector('.explanation').textContent = data.explanation
}

fetchAPOD()
```

which is working fine

all i want is to add feature to get images from the API randomly

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: updated the question.
please check once. I want to add random functionality via which it will show images from various dates randomly @mplungjan

Comment: but on the API documentation there is a query named 'count' randomly chosen images will be returned. @Andy

Comment: I have voted to reopen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *count* A positive integer, no greater than 100. If this is specified then count randomly chosen images will be returned in a JSON array. Cannot be used in conjunction with date or start_date and end_date.

https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pymfg2uv/

```js
const imgDiv = document.getElementById("imageDiv");

fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&count=3`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  imgDiv.innerHTML = data.map(item => `<div>
 <h3 class="title">${item.title} <span class="date">${item.date}</span></h3>
 <img src="${item.url}" />
 <p>${item.explanation}</p></div>`).join('')

})
```

```css
.date { font-size: xx-small; }
```

```html
<div id="imageDiv"></div>
```

Older answer with one random image from a date range

```js
const img = document.getElementById("apod");
let date, start = Date.parse('2021-01-01'), end = new Date();
end.setDate(end.getDate()-1);
const getDate = () => { 
  date = new Date(Math.floor(Math.random() * (end - start + 1) + start)).toISOString().split('T')[0]; 
  return date
};

fetch(`https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=DEMO_KEY&start_date=${getDate()}&end_date=${date}`)
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  img.src = data[0].url
})
```

```html
<img id="apod" />
```

Comment: thanks sir it worked
but how can i change the images?

Comment: What do you mean? Put it in a function and call it again if you need to do it again. You need an event like a click? But that is not what you asked so that is not what I answered

Comment: no i mean after using count it will give list of objects 
how can i list all those objects on my page @mplungjan

sorry for my bad explanation

Comment: @Subhadeep98Ares So did this work for you?

Comment: sorry yesterday SO was down for maintenance
it's working absolutely fine
marked it Right

Thanks a lot for helping Sir @mplungjan

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/v8qfgkh4/ here it is

Comment: @Subhadeep98Ares Without reloading: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/pymfg2uv/

Comment: great. updated it.